# Time of last edit of an xml file in WinRT - Windows 8 - Metro App

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-8, windows-runtime, xml-serialization

my question is the following. I wonder if it is possible to know what the last edit time is for an xml file.

Currently i am creating my xml and reading from my xml in the following way:

This is the writing part, i am serialising an observable collection:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<DomExistingVacationDays>));
                using (IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccess = await VacationRequestOfflineHolidaysFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (IOutputStream sessionOutputStream = sessionRandomAccess.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(sessionOutputStream.AsStreamForWrite()))
                        {
                            xs.Serialize(wr, _existingHolidaysCollection);
                        }
                    }

                }
```

This is the reading part, deserialising the observable collection:

```
 XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<DomExistingVacationDays>));
                using (IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccess = await VacationRequestOfflineHolidaysFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (IInputStream sessionInputStream = sessionRandomAccess.GetInputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(sessionInputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
                        {
                            _existingHolidaysCollection = xs.Deserialize(rd) as ObservableCollection<DomExistingVacationDays>;
                        }
                    }

                }
```

what i want to achieve is that when the data in the xml file is older than let's day a few days i no longer wish to use it.

So i could add a datetime to the xml file, but i would like to know if there isn't any other solution to this problem.

Thnx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably looking for `File.GetCreationTime(path)` and/or `File.GetLastWriteTime(path)` (namespace System.IO).

In Win8 UI apps you may want to use `StorageFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()`. The returned `BasicProperties` contains `DateModified`. Also `StorageFile.DateCreated` could be of interest.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean or how i should use this. Which class should i use in order to implement this ?

Comment: @Landvis namespace=`System.IO` classname=`File` methodname=`GetCreationTime` :)

Comment: Have a look at the documentation in MSDN. The File class is a static class with some (static) functions. So you don't need to open the file (which is an advantage with respect to other classes like FileSystemInfo and FileInfo). You would call `File.GetLastWriteTime(...)` with the parameter pointing to the xml file. Then you could compare the returned DateTime with whatever you need.

Comment: Yes, i have looked into this and found out that in MetroApps FileInfo class is no longer available, it has from what i found been replaced with StorageFile in WinRT metroapps

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this thnx to the help from  @JeffRSon by using the StorageFile class. The FileInfo class has been replaced with the StorageFile class in MetroApps.
Once i had the storageFile i used following code:

```
var documentProperties = await OfflineRFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
var dateLastModified = documentProperties.DateModified;
```

OfflineRFile is my StorageFile.

Thnx for the quick responses